# how can i make divs with irregular shape

Tags: html, css

how can i create a two divs shown in images one div should be in pink color and other one in blue color.I want to create same shapes like in this example but with using two divs

[example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NC7A.png)

Comment: anything you tried that we can improve ?

Comment: actually i dont know that how to start creating this type of images

Comment: what is your actual HTML and CSS ? are those divs meant to be filled with content ?

Answer (score 1):

Using css transform skew property you can skew the right container and shift it to the left. Note the right end of the skewed container is strategically hidden by applying an overflow hidden property to the parent container

Snippet below

```css
#container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ED145B;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #212635;
}

#right {
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  right: 10%;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw the colors are #ED145B (pink) and #212635 (blue)

Comment: preferred color code added

Answer (score 0):

```css
.skew {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg); /* Chrome, Opera */
      -ms-transform: skew(0deg); /* IE */
          transform: skew(0deg); /* Padrão */
}

.positive {
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg); /* Chrome, Opera */
      -ms-transform: skew(10deg); /* IE */
          transform: skew(10deg); /* Padrão */
}

.negative {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg); /* Chrome, Opera */
      -ms-transform: skew(-10deg); /* IE */
          transform: skew(-10deg); /* Padrão */
  }
```

```html
<span>0 DEG</span>
<div class="skew"></div>

<span>10 DEG</span>
<div class="skew positive"></div>

<span>-10 DEG</span>
<div class="skew negative"></div>
```